# Html pattern for a specific pattern

Tags: html, regex

I have to try to write a pattern that accepts a character in the form of `S0000/0000/0000` or `P0000/0000/0000` Where 0 is any number

This is what I have a try

```
  <input class="form-control" type="text" pattern="^\d{5}/\d{4}/\d{4}$" name="index_no" required>
```

But that pattern it only accepts 5 digits / 4 digits / 4 digits what I need is `S0000/0000/0000` OR `P0000/0000/0000`

Comment: `[A-Z]\d{4}\/\d{4}\/\d{4}` You say 5 digits, but what you apparently mean is one alphabetic character followed by 4 digits, a backslash, 4 digits, a backslash, and 4 digits. There are many tutorial sites on regular expressions. I suggest finding one, and using a tester to test your patterns. If it's truly S or P, use `(S|P)` in place of `[A-Z]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\` to escape special characters in html.
Try this,

```
pattern="[SP]\d{4}\/\d{4}\/\d{4}"
```

You can test for correctness of regex expressions in this [tester site](https://www.regextester.com/)

Comment: There is no need escaping `/` in string patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I misunderstood your requirement initially, please try this edited HTML

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" pattern="S\d\d\d\d/\d\d\d\d/\d\d\d\d|P\d\d\d\d/\d\d\d\d/\d\d\d\d" name="index_no" required>
```

Comment: No need repeating `\d` so many times, use a range quantifier.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
pattern="[SP]\d{4}/\d{4}/\d{4}"
```

You need no `^` and `$` as the entire string should match `pattern` regex.

No need to escape `/` characters in a string regex.